# Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Blob'

Tags: typescript

I have a blob (naming it `file`) and I am trying to store its name value by doing something like this

```
properties.name = file.name;
```

but it's keep complaining about

```
Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Blob'.
```

The quick fix they suggested adds name to `blob` in TypeScript node_modules folder which I don't want to.

What are the suggestion/options I should do to fix this error? Sorry, I am new to TS and I am not sure what to search.

This is my image blob `console.log`. It could be possible (from comment) that library I am using might have added blob

```
lastModified: 1596803874299
lastModifiedDate: Fri Aug 07 2020 18:07:54 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) {}
name: "photo of Elizabeth Tower, London-gcffb6skhv.jpg"
size: 408146
type: "image/jpeg"
webkitRelativePath: ""
```

Comment: [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) simply has no `name` property which means the compiler will complain that you're trying to access a property that's just not there.

Comment: @MikeS. `console.log(blob)` does log a property name in console?

Comment: You can do this in javascript because there are no types and it'll let you assign to properties and just add them to the object, but in typescript you want to be aware of every property and it's type.

Comment: @MikeS. How can I add property name? or fix this error?

Comment: Have you tried  `properties.name = file['name'];`

Comment: According to specification, there is no `name`, only `type`
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Blob

Comment: @Namysh I don't think this would fix it. plus my linitng configuration won't allow it (and I don't want to change my lint configuration)

Comment: Is it possible that u access a File and not a Blob, File inherits from Blob

Comment: The proper way would be to make your own class and extend from `Blob` and add a name property, the quick way would be the one @Namysh provided.

Comment: @Estradiaz The library I am using returns blob instead of file

Comment: What kind of library you are using? Maybe it is possible to import extended Blob from lib

Comment: @AlexanderAlexandrov https://github.com/elninotech/uppload

Comment: yeah then typeguard it into File or just dirty `as unknown as File`

Comment: @Estradiaz can you please elaborate?

Comment: Maybe you have confused Blob with File?
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/File/name

Comment: okay, So I did something like this `_.get(file, "name", "");` and it works but I don't think this is the right way to do it :)

Answer (score 7):

I know that this is a 1 year and 7 months old question, but just ran into this issue myself.

The solution here is to use the type File that extends Blob.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

A `Blob` can be of the [File type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File). In this context you will want to use a `File` type.

> A File object is a specific kind of Blob, and can be used in any context that a Blob can.

A `File` object contains the name property you are looking for.

Example interface:

```
interface FormValues {
  title: string;
  description: string;
  file: File | null; // See the File type here
}
```